# How to divide row by row for the same float column in Python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe with float columns X and Y and the string column A.
The content of float columns are positive float numbers.

I am extracting the row where  column A='a' and another row where column A = 'b'
and I am doing division of float columns of 2 rows (a/b) as in code below.
The problem is that result of division is NaN. Why?
I tried to use axis=0 and axis=1 but result is the same.

I am using python pandas version 1.0.5
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
    ddd = {
      'A': ['a', 'b'],
      'X': [100.0, 20.0],
      'Y': [6.0, 2.0]
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(ddd)
    df1 = df[df['A'] =='a']
    df2 = df[df['A'] == 'b']
    print(df1)
    print(df2)`

    res = df1.iloc[:, 1:].div(df2.iloc[:, 1:], axis=0)
    print(res)

    res = df1.iloc[:, 1:].div(df2.iloc[:, 1:], axis=1)
    print(res)
```

Result

```
   X    Y
 0 NaN NaN
 0 NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.div` will only work on the two rows if the indices are the same so you need to use:

```
df2 = df[df['A'] == 'b'].reset_index(drop=True)
```

which then will gives for res:

```
     X    Y
0  5.0  3.0
```

Comment: This answer works. However, when I  added 2 more rows to  dataframe with col(A) = 'c' and col(A)='d' and I tried to call code above in the loop over pairs of values in llst = [('a','b'), ('c','d')]  where every element in every tuple is matching column A , 1st element nominator and 2nd is denominator I have found that only 1st division for tuple (a.b) works as expected,  
for the second tuple ('c','d') it returns  row with (NaN , NaN  )

Answer (score 1):

Don't use boolean indexing. Rather set "A" as index:

```
ddd = {
      'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      'X': [100.0, 20.0, 5.0, 2.0],
      'Y': [6.0, 2.0, 1.0, 1.0]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(ddd).set_index('A')

lst = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
out = [df.loc[x]/df.loc[y] for x, y in lst]
```

Output:

```
[X    5.0
 Y    3.0
 dtype: float64,
 X    2.5
 Y    1.0
 dtype: float64]
```

Or, index all combinations at once:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(ddd).set_index('A')
lst = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]

x, y = map(list, zip(*lst))

out = (df.loc[x].div(df.loc[y].values)
         .set_axis(lst)
       )
```

Output:

```
          X    Y
(a, b)  5.0  3.0
(c, d)  2.5  1.0
```

`df`:

```
       X    Y
A            
a  100.0  6.0
b   20.0  2.0
c    5.0  1.0
d    2.0  1.0
```

*NB. I'm assuming letters in "A" are unique.*

If you have missing values,`reindex`:

```
ddd = {
      'A': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      'X': [100.0, 20.0, 5.0],
      'Y': [6.0, 2.0, 1.0]
    }

df = pd.DataFrame(ddd).set_index('A')
lst = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]

x, y = map(list, zip(*lst))

out = (df.reindex(x).div(df.reindex(y).values)
       .set_axis(lst)
       )

          X    Y
(a, b)  5.0  3.0
(c, d)  NaN  NaN
```